# I need all name servers (DNS) in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

If there are multiple NICs on a machine, and each NIC is configured for multiple name servers, I need a list of all of them.

I have written simple java code to parse ipconfig /all in Windows (I need this in java), but getting the same information in Linux seems unclear from researching.

Some articles say "cat /etc/resolv.conf". Some say that is the old way for some distributions and to use nmcli with appropriate arguments and just parse the information.

My research has led me to believe the following is how it probably should be done:

1. Check of nmcli is available
2. Check if network-manager is on
3. if so, parse nmcli output
4. if not, parse cat /etc/resolv.conf

I am not an expert in linux, so I am seeking validation or correction here.

Thanks for answering!

EDIT: If it helps, I care about RHEL6+ and Suse 11

EDIT2: So per Suse's documentation, parsing resolv.conf seems to be sufficient because they just update the file. Still looking into RHEL.

Comment: What about name servers that aren't DNS?

Comment: As you're trying to support multiple OS's (and versions?), your 4+ step approach seems very reasonable. Except for installing python or perl (and wrestling with complexity of the already installed versions VS the "best" version), there won't be a generic solution that will work for all cases, so depending on the importance of this, you may become the expert on this topic for your team. Even w one of the P languages, you probably wouldn't be able to write one block of code that would work on all systems without installing a few special libraries. Good luck!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am no specialist, but I thought all name servers responded to DNS requests. I just need it to tell me if a FQDN resolves.

Comment: Any entry in the `hosts` name service database can serve names.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like reading resolv.conf is a safe bet for the current releases of RHEL and Suse.